# Recaptcha not rendering

Tags: django, recaptcha

This should be totaly simple, but I guess I must be missing something..

I put this in the html body, before the form:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js" async defer></script>
```

Then inside a form I have this recaptcha div:

```
...
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="[MY_API_KEY]"></div>
    ...
```

When the page loads, there's no recaptcha and also firebug's console doesn't output anything. What could be wrong?

EDIT: Now it actually works sometimes, but I have to refresh the page, but it's totally random if it works or not. This is really strange behaviour.

Comment: add `<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>` after form, and test

Comment: i had to put it after the form, and remove "async defer"

Comment: DAMN! now I just puted it in the table and it stopped working... <tr><td>Captcha</td><td><div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div></td></tr>    WTF?

Comment: This is strange. Now it randomly works from time to time. Wtf is this?! This should be 100% relyable!

Comment: I just discovered that if you reload the page using Ctrl+Shift+R (on Firefox), it usually works.

Comment: Why do you send information to the search engines? can't you do it yourself? Already you're using python.

Comment: The reCAPTCHA page itself says to put the `script` tag inside   the `head` tag, so it should load before everything else. Also, try using different browsers!

Comment: @TheJuniorProgrammer, after reading your comment i realized, that I have two script tags included. One was already in my header template. So this was the problem. What should I do with this question? Is it still relevant after we discovered that it was just the sloppiness of a programmer. And only a few hours until the reputation is wasted. Do you mind creating an answer?

Comment: Sure, thanks for the rep!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reCAPTCHA page itself says to put the `script` tag inside the `head` tag, so it should load before everything else. Also, check if you have two `script` tags...*wink*

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the `async` and `defer` attributes from your script tag and place it somewhere above your form.

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'></script>
```

This will ensure that your script is run before your form is parsed.

the `api.js` is only ~532 bytes (minified) and shouldn't add much overhead to your page loading.

Also I'm not sure if this question is related to `django` in anyway. I suggest you remove that tag from your question :)

Hope this helps and best of luck.

Comment: Thanks. I have removed async and defer, but it's still not working. I can remove the django tag, but I cannot say for sure that this is not releated to django.

Comment: Did you also move the script tab to the top of your page? or before the form tag? from what you had described it sounded like the was a matter of the script not being loaded fully before your form was parsed. but when you refreshed the page the second time the script could have been cached and that could have been why it was working after a refresh.

Answer (score 0):

i got similar problem with chart.js on my website.

If, it is same case with me (when reload page works), i think js file doesn't downloaded until your html rendering.

check safari or chrome resource download time.
if your screen is ready and recapcha.js is until downloading, you should add set timeout or etc to wait for your javascript code.

i tried like this..

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    Chart.defaults.global.tooltipFontSize= 10;
    Chart.defaults.global.scaleShowLabels=false;
}, 10)
```